# Cannot install e(fx)clipse to Eclipse Mars

Tags: java, eclipse, efxclipse

I have a problem with e(fx)clipse. I cannot install it into Eclipse Mars. I followed a tutorial from here: https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html#for-the-ambitious

[image]

[image]

As you can see in the second image, an IDE Mars doesn't appear and if I chose e(fx)clipse-IDE an error occurs.

Comment: I've just installed e(fx)clipse in an Eclipse Mars Eclipse (Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Build id: 20160218-0600) and got no errors. Maybe there is some conflict or dependence with your installed plug-ins

Answer (score 0):

You can try downloading a pre-packaged version of Eclipse + e(fx)clipse that is available at http://efxclipse.bestsolution.at/

I had some luck getting the various Eclipse dependencies to work with that, but I still ran into other errors when trying to use the sample projects that e(fx)clipse provides, but hope you have better luck.